# How do I get notified when new answers or comments appear on certain questions?

Tags: support

How can I get an email notification whenever new answers or comments appear to certain questions that I'm interested in?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can get notification for selected tags:
read [this post on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25224/email-notifications-for-new-questions-matching-specific-tags).

**One option** is adding tags to your *RSS feed*:

Hover over a tag in the [Emacs SE tags page](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags) then click on the rss icon.

**A second option is:**

navigate to [tags filter page](https://stackexchange.com/filters/351669/my-filter) and fill the simple form with the filter details and your email address.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not looking to get notified on all questions that match a given tag, but only on specific questions.

For example, let's say I was not the one who started this question.  How would I get an email notification when someone commented on or answered this question in particular?